# What is the relationship between font-size and x/y percentages for positioning text elements in an SVG?

Tags: svg

I am trying to center text in an area based on some shapes.

In the example below, each square has a height and width of 50% of the SVG. I am trying to center the very large "X" character. Intuitively, I thought setting the text's x and y to the center of any square (25%,25% or 25%,75% or 75%,75% or 75%,25%), but it is off. I need to adjust the percentage a little more to center them.

In the example below, it looks like my intuition is wrong in the upper left square, whereas adjusting the y% a little centers it in the upper right square. The smaller blue and green squares are included to show exactly where 25%,25% and 25%,75% are.

I notice that this changes when font size changes as well. Is there a way to center text based on the font size using percentages? What key concept am I missing for understanding why this doesnt work?

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <style>
.f{font-family:monospace;font-size:80pt}
  </style>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="0%" fill="red"/>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="50%" fill="green"/>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="0%" x="50%" fill="yellow"/>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="50%" x="50%" fill="blue"/>
  
  <text x="25%" y="25%" class="f" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">X</text>
  <text x="75%" y="29%" class="f" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="blue">X</text>
  <rect width="25%" height="25%" y="25%" x="25%" fill="blue"/>
  <rect width="25%" height="25%" y="25%" x="75%" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: @RobertLongson huh, apparently it is. works with all different kinds of font sizes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want dominant-baseline="central" rather than middle.

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <style>
.f{font-family:monospace;font-size:80pt}
  </style>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="0%" fill="red"/>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="50%" fill="green"/>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="0%" x="50%" fill="yellow"/>
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" y="50%" x="50%" fill="blue"/>
  
  <text x="25%" y="25%" class="f" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle">X</text>
  <text x="75%" y="29%" class="f" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="blue">X</text>
  <rect width="25%" height="25%" y="25%" x="25%" fill="blue"/>
  <rect width="25%" height="25%" y="25%" x="75%" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The font allows for all characters to be displayed.

You need to change the baseline

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/baseline-shift

[image]